# Webpack: How to configure webpack to keep last 3 build files

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

My webpack is configured to generate new js files every time when content changes `[name][contenthash].js`. But it creates problems in runtime when using lazy loading of chunks.

After the new build, old files are deleted and new ones are created with new hashes. If a user this time tries to open a new page, `app.[hash].js` file fails to load the `product.[contenthash].js` file, because its name has already changed after build. Users have to reload the page to load it and they can lose some filled data.

Is there any way to configure webpack clean to keep the last versions of build files?